# Why is there a fight amongst Sri Vaishnavas regarding "namam" of Lord Venkateshwara?

Tags: temple, sri-vaishnava, tradition

There is a strong controversy going on since years about the forehead tilaka.style among both sects of sri vaishnava.

> The rivalry between the Tenkalai and Vadakalai sects of Iyengar
>   Brahmins plunged to lower levels recently, with a fresh controversy
>   emerging at the holy Hindu hill shrine of Venkateswara in Tirumala
>   over how the idol should look. One of the groups has decided to move
>   court against the other over the alleged change in the style of
>   "Namam" or forehead-mark of the presiding deity.
>
> According to a report in Deccan Chronicle, members of one sect
>   intentionally changed the style of "namam" on the forehead of the idol
>   of Lord Venkateswara. Though it is unclear as to which sect changed
>   it, the TTD has allegedly excused the accused priest from Abhishekam
>   duty.   Priests of the Vadakalai sect wear the Tirunamam or U-shaped
>   namam, while those of the Tenkalai sect wear it in the shape of  the
>   alphabet ‘Y’. An apparent change in practice on what adorns the sacred
>   idol has resulted in one of the sects planning to approach a court of
>   law against the other sect.

[Source](http://www.thenewsminute.com/article/tirumala-brahmin-wars-why-does-it-matter-what-shape-namam)

Why is there a fight amongst the Sri Vaishnavas regarding "namam" of Lord Venkateshwara?